# Outlook scales the dialog boxes wrong so the controls aren't all visible

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, display-settings

On my Windows 7 laptop Outlook 2010's settings dialogs are sized wrong so I can't use them. Here's what it looks like when trying to set up or change email account settings. 
[image: Outlook dialogs sized incorrectly]

I tried changing the font scaling in Windows. (Right-click desktop, Properties, Display in the left sidebar) It was set to Smaller 100% so I changed it to Medium 125% (default). Logged off and back on and it made the problem even worse. The dialog boxes got a LOT bigger and the controls were scaled even farther off the edge of the dialog. In the Change Account dialog the Test Account area wasn't even visible, the text boxes for name and email address ran all the way out the right side of the form.

Any ideas of how to fix this short of reinstalling Windows 7 or accepting Microsoft annoying nagging to upgrade to Windows 10?

My email provider recently changed from non-secure email to secure email. In order to fix it I have to click the off-screen Advanced button below the Text Account check box to get to the advanced settings. Then I have to change the dropdown boxes off the right side of the advanced tab. I can't see what they are so it's just a guess how I set them if I blindly use the arrow keys to change them. Makes it hard to complain to the email host and tell them I know for sure I have it set correctly when I can't ever be sure I set it correctly.

Comment: Oh, I searched but didn't see that one. I'll go check it out.

Comment: No freaking way! That's all it was? The Tahoma font got deleted from my system? I've lived with this issues for at least a couple years. Thank you @DavidPostill, if I could mark a comment as an answer I would. The proper course is to delete my question though. I don't know why I'm even posting this comment because it will be deleted too.

Comment: The proper course is to accept the duplicate. Then this question will act as another signpost to the answer :)